# Why does the keyboard not appear on the iPhone X simulator in Xcode 9?

Tags: ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

I just ran an app that I am developing on the iPhone X simulator in Xcode 9.1.  The soft keyboard doesn't appear when I tap inside of a UITextView.  It works fine in the iPhone 8 simulator.  To trouble shoot I ran the calendar app on the iPhone X simulator and selected the search icon.  Again, no keyboard popped up.

Anyone else seeing this behavior or have a fix?

Comment: `⌘ ` + `k` didn't worked ?

Comment: Will give that a shot tonight when I get home, but when a uitextview gets the focus it should appear on its own.

Comment: Once you toggle keyboard(`⌘` + `K`), it will enable until you toggle again.

Comment: Had the hardware keyboard on.  Shift + CMD + K fixed it.  Thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason this was happening to me was because the hardware keyboard was on, so the soft keyboard wouldn't appear.  Shift + CMD + K fixed it.  Not sure why that was on by default though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the keyboard is affected by the blue-tooth selfie stick. Reset iPhone blue-tooth which disconnects the selfie stick fixed the problem.